# PHP: How to detect how many time interval in minutes includes between two DateTime?

Tags: php, datetime, intervals

i have two DateTime

```
$datetime1 = date_create_from_format('H:i', '12:10');
$datetime2 = date_create_from_format('H:i', '18:16');
```

and i have interval in minutes, some for examlpe 56 minutes

How many times this interval includes between $datetime1 and $datetime2?

I try

```
$diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2)
```

but object $diff do not include this information

Comment: Take a look at ``DateInterval::format``.

Answer (score 0):

```
(strtotime($datetime2) - strtotime($datetime1))/56*60*60
```

This will give you then number of intervals in between two datetimes

Comment: strtotime converts the php datetime in unix timestamp

Answer (score 0):

Using `DateTime` you could do the following.

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime( '12:10' );
$datetime2 = new DateTime( '18:16' );

$diff      = $datetime1->diff( $datetime2 );

$total     = $diff->i + ( $diff->h * 60 );

echo $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

> but object $diff do not include this information

It does, you just have to find it. Use the `h` and `i` attributes :

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create_from_format('H:i', '12:10');
$datetime2 = date_create_from_format('H:i', '18:16');

$diff = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$minutes_diff = $diff->h * 60 + $diff->i;
var_dump($minutes_diff); // int(366)

$interval = 56;
$times_interval = $minutes_diff / $interval;
var_dump($times_interval); // float(6.5357142857143)

?>
```

Comment: This is very like me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Taras Germanyuk From Ukraine, for things like this, DateTime is your friend: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php, http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php. It makes these kinds of calculations easy.

```
<?php
$d1 = new DateTime('12:10');
$d2 = new DateTime('18:16');

$interval = $d1->diff($d2);

echo ($interval->format('%i') + ($interval->format('%h') * 60));
?>
```